# Get HTML data attribute or ID value from one page and pass to another page as PHP variable

Tags: php, html, variables, attributes, anchor

I have an anchor tag as such:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" data-trackid="'.$row['track_id'].'" class="edit_button edit_track" id="'.$row['track_id'].'">Edit</a>
```

I need to grab either the ID or DATA attribute value and send that to another page as a PHP variable so that I can echo it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you use `href="somepage.php?id=yourid"` ?

Comment: I'm opening a "thickbox" (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/), which is why I'm using javascript:void(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `thickbox` you can do something like example 4a on http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        contentContainer:'.content',
        loadUrl: 'somepage.php?id='+$('.edit_track').attr('id') //Uses jQuery.load()
});
```

Comment: Problem is I have the popup incorporated into the page I need it to load into and just have it as a hidden div via css until bpopup shows it.  It may be a possibility if I can't get it this way, but I'd like to see if there's a solution to the question first.

Comment: I think we're veering from the original question.

Comment: i am not sure what do you want to do with it. The solution depends on what you gonna do with the passed value. For example you can use ajax to pass the value to php. So it depends. Unless you tell more about it , its hard!!

Comment: hmm..ok.  Then how would I grab two attributes to put into the loadURL, such as `loadUrl:'somepage.php?id='+$('.edit_track').attr('id')&track_id='+$('.edit_track').attr('track_id')`

Comment: u can grab two ids with this...
loadUrl:'somepage.phpid='+$('.edit_track').attr('id')&track_id='+$('.edit_trac‌k').attr('data-trackid')...

Comment: works now.  thank you! This is what I ended up with `loadUrl:'edit.php?id='+$('.edit_track').attr('id')+'&track='+$('.edit_track').attr('data-uniqueid')`

Answer (score 0):

u have an option in thickbox called LoadUrl ... u can use that if i am not wrong...

JQUERY

```
 $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        contentContainer:'.content',
        loadUrl: 'urphppage.php?id='+ $('.edit_track').attr('id') // url to your page with the id value
    });
```

PHP(urphppage.php)

```
$id=$_GET['id'];  // get the id value
echo $id;
```